# C# Доступ к полям

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс *User* в которого есть пустой конструктор и 2 public поля Id и Name:

```
private long id;
public long Id {
  get => this.id;
  set => this.id = value;
}


private string name;
public string Name {
  get => this.name;
  set => this.name = value;
}
```

Вопрос: Когда я получаю данные из базы данных и создаю новый экземпляр класса мне нужно указать Id как и иметь возможность читать его в будущем, но когда я делаю insert в базу данных Id указывать мне не нужно, и видеть как поле наверное тоже. Мне просто создать метод для insert и параметрами которые мне нужны (без Id) или как-нибудь можно обыграть с видимостью полей?

Comment: [XY problem](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/218063)? Опишите реальную задачу

Comment: Проблема создана на пустом месте, обыгрывать ничего не надо. Для Insert вы создаете экземпляр класса с нулевым значением Id, и передаете в метод, который работает с БД.

Comment: @Bulson при условии что Id - автоинкремент и уникальный ключ.